# "this.props.dispatch is not a function" when i use redux-search package

Tags: redux

I add redux to my react application, and my case is:

I have a component has tabs tow categories called: **(topics, files)** each one has tree list of data, I need to search inside the activated tab, I found [redux-search](https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-search) library to make searchable resources.

I will add a snippet of my code, please make a review to my redux code and redux-search package implementation.

**TopicsReducer:**

```
  export default function reducer(state = {
     topics: [], // should be searchble state.
     files: [], // should be searchble state.
     fetching: false,
     fetched: false,
     error: null
  }, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case "FETCH_TOPICS_PENDING": {
        return {...state, fetching: true};
    }

    case "FETCH_TOPICS_REJECTED": {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
    }

    case "FETCH_TOPICS_FULFILLED": {
        return {
            ...state,
            fetching: false,
            fetched: true,
            topics: action.payload
        }
    }

    case "FETCH_FILES_FULFILLED": {
        return {
            ...state,
            fetching: false,
            fetched: true,
            files: action.payload
        }
    }
  }

      return state;
  }
```

**store.js**

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from "redux";
import {reduxSearch} from 'redux-search'
import reducer from './reducers';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from 'redux-logger'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger);
const redux_search = reduxSearch({
  resourceIndexes: {
      topics: ['title', 'description'] // HERE should i tell reduxSearch i have topics and files
  },
  resourceSelector: (resourceName, state) => {
      return state.topics[resourceName]
  }
});

 export default createStore(reducer, compose(middleware, redux_search));
```

In the component:

```
import React from "react";
import {Tab, TabList, TabPanel, Tabs} from "react-tabs";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store';
import TreeNode from "./partials/TreeView/TreeNode";
import Search from "./partials/search";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchTopics} from "../actions/topicsActions";
import {createSelector} from 'reselect'
import {createSearchAction, getSearchSelectors} from 'redux-search'


const topics = state => state.topics;  // NOTE: i was using getIn()like in repo but show me error in console getIn is not a function for this i don't used.

const {
       text,
       result
      } = getSearchSelectors({
          resourceName: 'topics',
          resourceSelector: (resourceName, state) => 
               state.topics[resourceName]
      });

    const selectors = createSelector(
    [result, topics, text],
    (topicId, topics, searchText) => ({
          topicId,
          topics,
          searchText
     })
  );

  const actions = {
        searchTopics: createSearchAction('topics')
  };

@connect(selectors, actions)
class Topics extends React.Component { ....
```

And inside the component, I use a function to despatching data when changing the tab.

```
 // index: tab index.
 fetchData(index = this.state.tabIndex) {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchTopics(index))
 }
```

console error :
[image]

- who fix this error?
- is this implementation work with me to searching inside topics and files?

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` is only injected to the wrapped component if `mapDispatchToProps` is not provided.

From the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> If you do not supply your own `mapDispatchToProps` function or object full of action creators, the default `mapDispatchToProps` implementation just injects `dispatch` into your component’s props.

If you want to include `dispatch` in addition to your actions, try:

```
const actions = (dispatch) => ({
    ...bindActionCreators({ searchTopics: createSearchAction('topics') }, dispatch),
    dispatch
})
```